# Can I read the output of the function POpen(...).communicate into multiple lines?

Tags: python, subprocess, stdout, stdin

I'm trying to use a subprocess for wrapping the viur-cli command line interface.
(https://pypi.org/project/viur-cli/)

Actually the communicate function works fine, but there is one problem with it. The result of the output text is not splitted into mulitple lines.

Here is a part of my code for it:

```py
class ViurCommandContext(object):
    def __init__(self, sub_cmd: str, *args) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self._process: Popen = None
        self._sub_cmd: str = sub_cmd
        self._args: List[str] = args
        self._output: BytesIO = BytesIO()
        self._send_list: List[str] = list()
        self._err = None

    def __enter__(self):
        logging.debug(f"Open new sub process with the command {self.command}")
        self._process = Popen(self.command, stdin = PIPE, stdout = PIPE, stderr = PIPE, encoding='utf-8', universal_newlines=True)
        # self._process = Popen(self.command, stdin = PIPE, encoding='utf-8', bufsize=650001)
        return self

    def send_line(self, text: str = '') -> None:
        self._send_list.append(text + os.linesep)
        logging.debug(f"[{self._process.pid}] Append {text} to the queue.")

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        rep = "".join(self._send_list)
        print(rep.encode("utf-8"))
        
        self._output, self._err = self._process.communicate(rep)
        print(self._output)

with ViurCommandContext(name, *args) as context:
    context.send_line("y")
    context.send_line("1")
    context.send_line("1")
    context.send_line("project-name")
    context.send_line("abc")
    context.send_line("n")
    context.send_line("n")
    context.send_line("n")
```

The command got executed properly and without any problems. Just the output of the function communicate looks weird:

`project.json already exists, do you want to delete it and create a new project.json? [y/N]: distribution folder [./deploy]: distribution folder [./sources]: application name: develop version name: Do you want to use a prebuild Vi? (default) [Y/n]: Do you want to add vi as submodule(default) [Y/n]: Do you want to add additional flare application? [y/N]:`

But I expect a output like this:

`project.json already exists, do you want to delete it and create a new project.json? [y/N]: \ndistribution folder [./deploy]:\n distribution folder [./sources]:\n application name:\n develop version name: Do you want to use a prebuild Vi? (default) [Y/n]:\n Do you want to add vi as submodule(default) [Y/n]:\n Do you want to add additional flare application? [y/N]:\n`

For giving more information this is the simple command flow:

```sh
cian@work:~/Projects/viur-ui-server$ viur init
project.json already exists, do you want to delete it and create a new project.json? [y/N]: y
distribution folder [./deploy]:   
distribution folder [./sources]: 
application name: DEV
develop version name: 1.01.2021
Do you want to use a prebuild Vi? (default) [Y/n]: n
Do you want to add vi as submodule(default) [Y/n]: n
Do you want to add additional flare application? [y/N]: n
```

Is there any solution for it?

Comment: Is the difference between the two outputs just adding `\n`?

Comment: @12944qwerty Yes, with the line feeds in the output I can easily split them into multiple lines

Comment: Just add `\n` to the end of each of the lines you want it to be on

Comment: But, actually communicate should do it automatically...

Comment: The program you're running relies on local echo for newlines after prompts -- meaning, it intentionally doesn't print newlines itself, because the terminal echoing the newlines the user typed while answering its prompts achieves the desired goal. Which makes this a question we have a duplicate for already in the knowledge base.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your answer! 
Is this enough? 
https://gist.github.com/co-dev10/2c8f3e369d0e545d56c69c33e174f4f7
How about install the viur-cli with  ```pip install viur-cli```

Comment: A link to `viur-cli` is the critical missing piece. In particular, looking up the code, it's calling `click.confirm()` for prompts -- you could arguably build a MRE that just does an `import click` and calls `click.confirm()` just once with no external dependencies.

Comment: See https://github.com/pallets/click/blob/6411f425fae545f42795665af4162006b36c5e4a/src/click/termui.py#L234 -- `click` is _intentionally_ not writing any newline after its prompts. That puts you firmly in the space the duplicate question covers.